# Возможно ли сделать картинку в Java невидимой?

Tags: java, изображения

Если у меня есть картинка, экспортированная таким образом: `Image img1 = new ImageIcon(“res/image.png”).gatImage();` и два прямоугольника: `Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 50);` и `Rectangle rec2 = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50);`. Мне надо так, чтобы при соприкосновении картинка убиралась с поля зрения(Куда-нибудь туда, за рамки)  ну или становилась невидимой. Как это можно реализовать.

Comment: позвольте задать вопрос: откуда должен исчезать? что за проект у вас? веб или десктоп...

Comment: Что-то вроде игры на JAVA, занялся этим чтобы скилл повысить :). А по моему вопросу, мне нужно чтобы при соприкосновении прямоугольников(rec1 и rec2) исчезала картинка (Img).